# Unrelated javascript executes when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

My project has a script on the landing page that repositions the footer when certain buttons are clicked and another script that positions it back to its original starting point when certain other buttons are clicked.

A script on a subordinate page (not the landing page) submits a file to upload, and on the click of that button, the code to position it back to its original starting point (RestoreFooter) is called.

I considered that the submit button click causes a page reload, and that may cause the footer to reposition to its starting point, but that's not the problem (as far as I could tell).

Here is the script to reposition the footer, and the script to set it back to its starting point:

```
<script>
function MoveFooter() {
    document.getElementById("footer_x").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("footer_y").style.visibility = "visible";   }
</script>

<script>
function RestoreFooter() {
console.log("here_RF");
document.getElementById("footer_y").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("footer_x").style.visibility = "visible";}
</script>
```

Here is the button script:

It has no call to execute either of the two functions above, but it does call RestoreFooter -- I know because the console.log function does log "here_RF" when the submit button is clicked

```
<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 10%;">
<button class="btn" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"    onsubmit="submit_btn.disabled = true; return true;">Create extension</button></div>
```

I also tried making it an ordinary button, not a submit button, but still the same problem:

```
<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 10%;">
<button class="btn" id="submit_btn">Create extension</button></div>
```

What causes this strange performance?

This is a fairly large project, so I've posted enough code to understand the problem.  If more code is needed, I'll post more.

Thanks very much.

EDIT:  I made a comment below about the likely source of this problem.  I'll post back later.

Comment: Please post enough code for us to reproduce the behaviour, not just understand what you described to happen.

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere else in your code you are installing the functions as event handlers on some element. Inline event attributes are not the only way to execute a function on submitting a form.

Comment: I'm looking for other places where this code may also be called; I'll post more soon.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: It turns out that the region (div) where this panel is located is set to call several functions when a user clicks anywhere within the div.  I have to override that behavior when this button is clicked.  I'll post back when I have the solution; this may be a very arcane issue, but others may need the answer in the future.

Comment: Instead of `return true`, use `event.stopPropagation()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough informations about the code, and you should post more details.

Suggests that add debugger to Step into the handler function line by line.
I suppose some code elsewhere might override the handler.

Comment: Yes, I posted an edit to my question, and a comment above -- I think I know the problem, and I'm working on posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my edit above, the button is in a div, and the div has a handler that calls a function to make certain changes in the DOM when a user clicks anywhere within the div region.  That propagates to children like my button.  I solved it by eliminating the function that fires whenever the region (div) is clicked. If I needed that functionality in some situations and not others I would need to specify all places where that function should be called.

I hope that clarifies the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53135947/edit) instead of answering it.